# binding library : returning untyped object - method definition

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

Part of a library I'm trying to bind returns an object -

```
Editor.prototype.getHandlers = function() {
  return {
    'shape.append': require('./draw/AppendShapeHandler'),
    'shape.create': require('./draw/CreateShapeHandler')
  };
};
```

What I can't figure out is how to specify the class type as the returned object is anonymous :

```
class type editor = object
  method getHandlers : ? Js.t Js.opt Js.meth
end
```

Could anyone suggest a way forward here?

Thanks

Nick

Comment: OCaml uses structural typing for objects. An object type doesn't need a name, that's just for convenience. An object type looks like this: `< method : type; ... >`.

Comment: Thanks - I was just trying to avoid having to specify the fields of the object type and use some form of phantom type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, perhaps something like:

```
class type editor = object
  method getHandlers : <shape_append : Js.js_string Js.t Js.meth> Js.t Js.meth
end
```

More example:

```
class type server = object
  method listen : int -> (unit -> unit) Js.callback -> unit Js.meth
  method close : (unit -> unit) Js.callback -> unit Js.meth
  method address :
            <address: Js.js_string Js.t Js.readonly_prop;
             family : Js.js_string Js.t Js.readonly_prop;
             port: Js.js_string Js.t Js.readonly_prop> Js.t Js.meth
end
```

This approach, of binding this way, works but as I learned in my OCaml nodejs bindings, its better to write at a higher level rather than do these bindings. https://github.com/fxfactorial/ocaml-nodejs (Look at early git history for many more examples like this)

Comment: Thanks for the example - your nodejs bindings were extremely helpful - can't wait for someone to write an ocaml generator for wast/wasm - hope you enjoyed Marrakech - wish I could have been there.